# Data duplicate when second record in database nil

Tags: sql, loops, go, variables

i have a simple function in Golang and i trying to read data from database. This return which i want when all record (at exact field) is not null (nil in Golang), but value of second record read from DB (at exact field) same with first record if value that field is nil.

```
struct StoreData {
    whois string
    names []string
}

func readDataFromDB() []StoreData {
    var storeData  StoreData
    var storeDatas []StoreData

    sqlStmt := `SELECT fld_names FROM tblNames`
    stmt, err := globals.Db.Prepare(sqlStmt)
    defer stmt.Close()

    rows, err := stmt.Query()
    var strNames string
    for rows.Next(){
        err := rows.Scan(&storeData.whois, &strNames)

        storeDatas = append(storeDatas, storeData)
    }

    return storeDatas
}
```

[image]

I must use strNames variable because data store in DB is string (type text in Maria DB), then read i convert string to array string
Can i help you?
Thanks!

Comment: Reset the variable at every loop: add `strNames=""` at the top of the for loop

Comment: i am a bit confused about the columns you are scanning out. fld_names is one yes - which is getting assigned to storeData.whois. Which column is strNames for? The code ,as is, should throw an error at the `.Scan` statement